# javascript only allow some scrolling

Tags: javascript, iphone, scroll

I'm building a small web based media player that has a basic structure like

```
<div id="content">
    <!-- Some stuff -->
    <div id="playlist" style="overflow-y: scroll">
        <ul>
            <li> </li>
            <!-- ... -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- more stuff -->
</div>
```

I built the player to fit exactly in the iphone window and I wish to disable the scrolling when someone moves their finger around the page. But I want to allow two finger scrolling inside the playlist div. I tried the *normal* route

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

but that disables two finger scrolling along with it.

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only `preventDefault` if the event originates from outside the playlist:

```
document.ontouchmove = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'playlist') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is when the event originates from inside the playlist. The little devil is sneaky.

Comment: Theoretically, that's exactly what this function should check for. Does it not work? I'm not so familiar with mobile vernacular; is two-finger scrolling different from `ontouchmove`?

Comment: No, I mean when someone touches a li element inside the playlist div `e.target.id` isn't playlist.

Comment: Then instead of checking `e.target.id`, you could add an `ontouchmove` event listener to `#playlist` whose only purpose is to do `e.stopPropagation`

Answer (score 2):

```
    document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
        var target = e.currentTarget;
        while(target) {
            if((target.id === 'playlist'))
                return;
            target = target.parentNode;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    };
```